# Changing sort order of answers on a profile page does not work anymore in Camino

Tags: bug, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

When I am on a user's profile page and try to change the sort order of the user's answers this does not work anymore. When I click on the link nothing happens. I also cannot move to the next page of his answers anymore.

I am using Camino 2.0.7 and Mac OS X (10.6.7). I realize Camino is not a widely used browser, so no hard feelings if this doesn't get fixed. On the other hand I would really appreciate it if it DOES get fixed.

Comment: Camino is not supported (see [supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/167443))